# How to Track State of Incoming call in flutter

Tags: flutter, events, call

I just want to make functionality based on Call Events, so how I track the state of call in flutter? Is there any way to make this functionality without method channel in flutter?

States I need

- Incoming call state
- Call Runnig
- Call Cut

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to access android broadcastreceiver functionality without using native code. However, there are packages available that can assist you in this regard. It's worth noting that these packages may have certain limitations.